# How do you write a conditional in a MySQL select statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL, and I want to do a sort of ternary statement in my SQL like:

```
SELECT USER_ID, ((USER_ID = 1) ? 1 : 0) AS FIRST_USER
  FROM USER
```

The results would be similar to:

```
USER_ID | FIRST_USER
1       | 1
2       | 0
3       | 0
etc.
```

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
SELECT USER_ID, (CASE USER_ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIRST_USER FROM USER
```

Comment: This is the preferable answer - CASE is ANSI standard, the query would work without alteration on SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres...

Answer (score 62):

```
SELECT USER_ID, IF(USER_ID = 1, 1, 0) AS FIRST_USER FROM USER
```

The [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) statement works similarly to the ternary ? : operator.

Comment: I was trying to conditionally pick column_a or column_b (using one as a fallback if the other was null) and this did it for me. Thank you!