# in sqlserver, need to select one of two columns, can a case statment do this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

My table:

Users (userID, col1, col2)

I want to make a generic stored procedure, but I need to return EITHER col1 or col2 in a query.

Can I case statement handle this situation?

SELECT userID, col1
FROM Users

OR

SELECT userID, col2
FROM Users

Comment: Is there a condition that determines which of the two columns you want to return?

Comment: Either return col1 or col2 based on what criteria?  Why not just return both columns?  Either way, yes a case statement should be able to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647961/how-do-you-write-a-conditional-in-a-mysql-select-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CASE:

```
SELECT t.userid,
       CASE
         WHEN [something to evaluate why to show col1 vs col2 ] THEN
           t.col1
         ELSE
           t.col2
       END
  FROM USERS t
```

Using COALESCE:

```
SELECT t.userid,
       COALESCE(t.col1, t.col2)
  FROM USERS t
```

COALESCE returns the first column value that isn't null, starting from the left.

Comment: Is there something to be gained from using a `case` clause instead of having two different queries chosen within an `if` statement?

Comment: @Loadmaster: Maintenance would be my 1st concern.  Two separate queries makes it easier for the two to diverge over time & return different results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you don't mind returning the same column names:

```
SELECT userID, ArbitraryCol = CASE WHEN @param = 1 then col1 ELSE col2 END
FROM Users
```

If you need the column headers to change, then you should use the IF statement

```
IF @param = 1
BEGIN
SELECT userID, col1 FROM Users
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT userID, col2 FROM Users
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL Server 2000/2005 is something like this.

```
select
   UserID,
   case UserID
      when 1 then Col1
      when 2 then Col2
      else 'boo'
   end as SpecialSituation
from
   Users
```

Answer (score -1):

It can, assuming you have a logical expression for when to return col1 instead of col2:

```
SELECT USERID CASE WHEN USERTYPE='X' THEN COL1 ELSE COL2 END FROM USERS
```

If col1 and col2 are of different types, you will need to use CAST or CONVERT to convert one to the other.

Comment: This is invalid syntax since you are combining the two types of `CASE` expressions.  You need to remove the `USERID` from the beginning.