# How to implement ternary conditional operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, conditional-operator

I want to implement ternary conditional operator in MySQL. I have a table in which one field id exist. Its value may be null. I want to display `id` in ternary conditional format like this:

```
select id = id == null ? 0 : id;
```

Is it possible in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you write a conditional in a MySQL select statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647961/how-do-you-write-a-conditional-in-a-mysql-select-statement)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Try this :

```
select if(Id is null, 0, id) as Id;
```

Comment: It's a shame there's no shorthand. If you just want to get the first value which equates to true, you have to check for `null` or `''` and maybe even `0`. mySQL is a bit of a duche sometimes

Comment: This one is shortest of them all. Good one

Answer (score 61):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) is your friend; you should read it!

It says:

> ```
> IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
> ```
>
> If `expr1` is not `NULL`, `IFNULL()` returns `expr1`; otherwise it returns
>   `expr2`.

And then lots of examples. This is equivalent to using a ternary conditional with a comparison to `NULL` and the comparison subject as the second operand; that it doesn't happen to use the symbols `?` and `:` to get you there is not really relevant to anything.

So, in your case:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`id`, 0) FROM `table`
```

If you're desperate to provide three operands explicitly (why?!), then switch to `IF`:

```
SELECT IF(`id` IS NULL, 0, `id`) FROM `table`
```

Comment: +1, but to answer the question: `CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END`

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Same thing, no? And `IFNULL` is terser.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Oh, I get it.

Comment: Sure, just to answer the question about ternary :)

Comment: In my case, I need to use `IF` instead of `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` because I'm migrating data to a different vendor database and don't want to import the non-null values, only interpret it as a generic status. `SELECT IF(a.cancellationReason IS NOT NULL, 'C', 'A')) as appointment_status` works for me.

Comment: "Read the documentation" is never the right answer on SO.  You're not just talking to the person who asked the question, you're talking to everybody who searches their way to the question in the future.  (Also, MySQL's documentation is *awful* as a quick reference.)

Comment: The documentation link in this answer redirects to "Page Not Found".

Answer (score 27):

There are two ways that you can implement the same logic as a ternary operator:

1. Use the `IF` function, eg. `IF(expression, true result, false result)`
2. Use the `CASE` expression, eg.

   ```
   CASE WHEN expression THEN <true result> ELSE <false_result> END
   ```

When you are checking for NULL then you can use the `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` functions, eg.

```
IFNULL(ID, 0)
COALESCE(ID, 0)
```