# SQL: Ternary operations

Tags: mysql, sql

In C++, you can do this:

```
T.x = (T.y > 1 && (T.x - T.y < 0)) ? 0 : (T.x - T.y)
```

which in [almost] plain english, is

```
if T.y > 1 and T.x-T.y < 0 then
    set T.x to 0
else 
    set T.x to T.x-T.y
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using just SQL, without using stored procs or triggers?

Comment: see : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1647961/584420

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN T.y > 1 AND (T.x - T.y) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE (T.x - T.y) END
```

Comment: Is the semicolon statement terminator valid here?

Comment: @onedaywhen You're correct. I've removed it, since it's a fragment rather than a complete statement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes its possible, take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html), it says:

> **IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)**
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3.

This untested code should be your case:

```
SELECT IF(((T.y > 1) and (T.x-T.y < 0)), 0, (T.x-T.y))
```

Comment: Seems the docs are wrong because `(expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL)` is UNKNOWN.

Comment: It means probably a statement like IF(0,Yes,No) or IF(NULL,Yes,No) would both return No

Answer (score 0):

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Check this manual for details [control-flow-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
SELECT *, 
      CASE WHEN (y > 1 AND x < y) THEN 0 ELSE (x - y) END AS result
 FROM T;
```