# MySql: Conditional Join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm getting duplicate rows because `B.column1` is ambiguous.

This is why I only want rows of table `B` where `column2` has entries like `'x'` or `'y'` (it does consist of i.e. `'x'`,`'y'`,`'z'`).

The priority of `'x'` is over `'y'`, so user rather `'x'` than `'y'`. I thought the condition in the last line would solve that problem:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B on B.column1=A.column1 
        AND B.column2= (IF(B.column2 = 'x','x','y'))
```

But it turned out that it's the same as I would write

```
   AND (B.column2 = 'x' OR B.column2 = 'y')
```

-> it joins both rows instead of only one.

Is there a (good) solution to this problem? Keep in mind that i might want to join more tables than only one.

---

**Edit**:

Won't work

```
(B.column2 = 'x' XOR B.column2 = 'y')
```

won't work either

```
(B.column2 = 'x' OR B.column2 = 'y') AND NOT (B.column2 = 'x' AND B.column2 = 'y')
```

which i would not even accept since its not `'x' rather than'y'`, but `either 'x' or 'y'`.
But it shows me that I'm probably having the false approach

---

**Edit2**:

I used a slighty different approach of Jean Jung:

I have decided to give more insight into the Problem, since i can't solve the problem with `conditional joins`. Now this is how it looks like with multiple tables I want to join:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM A
   LEFT JOIN I on I.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B on B.column1 = I.column1 
   LEFT JOIN J on J.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B AS C on C.column1 = J.column1 and B.column2 = C.column2
   LEFT JOIN K on K.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B AS D on D.column1 = K.column1 and C.column2 = D.column2
WHERE B.column2 = 'x'
UNION
SELECT 
   *
FROM A
   LEFT JOIN I on I.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B on B.column1 = I.column1 
   LEFT JOIN J on J.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B AS C on C.column1 = J.column1 and B.column2 = C.column2
   LEFT JOIN K on K.unique = A.unique
   LEFT JOIN B AS D on D.column1 = K.column1 and C.column2 = D.column2
WHERE B.column2 = '' AND A.unique NOT IN (
    SELECT 
       A.unique
    FROM A
       LEFT JOIN I on I.unique = A.unique
       LEFT JOIN B on B.column1 = I.column1 
       LEFT JOIN J on J.unique = A.unique
       LEFT JOIN B AS C on C.column1 = J.column1 and B.column2 = C.column2
       LEFT JOIN K on K.unique = A.unique
       LEFT JOIN B AS D on D.column1 = K.column1 and C.column2 = D.column2
    WHERE B.column2 = 'x'
)
```

This takes quite a while, but does its job. I'm not satisfied as it seems very inelegant, but if there is no better solution i'll go with this (and to be honest, I don't really understand, why this works).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but just a few notes: 1) you may also use `IN ('x', 'y' , ...)` if you have multiple entries (but don't go over a few hundreds e.g. 200 or you might have perf issues, because this doesn't use the index). 2) Have you tried using `GROUP BY b.column2`  ?

Comment: Im having the Problem that `GROUP BY b.column2` doesnt always get me the row with `x` but sometimes the row with `y`. But i rather want the row with `x` than the one with `y`. Is there a way to have a condition there?  `IN ('x', 'y' ,)` will give me both rows, but as stated before, i only rows with `x`. If theres no `x` in `GROUP BY b.column2`, then I want `y`, otherwhise he should not join the row

Comment: @Hamed I think he could not use `IN`, cause he needs a priority level in `'x','y'`. If a record matches `'x'` then he has to ignore another record that matches `'y'`, right?

Comment: @Jean you got it. if there is no `'x'`, only then take `'y'`. if both are not there, then dont join at all

Comment: @InsOp use of `UNION` clause is a problem for you? Need you to list `B.column2` in `SELECT` clause? How many values you want to compare like `'x','y'`, just `'x'` and `'y'`?

Comment: Try this: [Conditional SELECT SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647961/how-do-you-write-a-conditional-in-a-mysql-select-statement)

Comment: @JeanJung its only two values. how would i achieve it with union? if i use it: is it possible to join multiple tables (which all have the same `'x'` and `'y'` ?

Comment: @Hamed did not work, but thanks

Comment: The `UNION` join two different result sets with no redundant data. If you mount the select as `SELECT * FROM TABLEA, TABLEB WHERE TABLEB.COLUMN = 'x' UNION SELECT * FROM TABLEA, TABLEB WHERE TABLEB.COLUMN = 'y'`, you will have the `'x'`values as priority, but you will have to omit the  `TABLEB.COLUMN` in your `SELECT`clause, otherwise the two rows will be diferent and returned. For more info check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html.

Comment: i kept the `LEFT JOIN`s, but did a `UNION` nevertheless. then i made a `WHERE` clause to the second `SELECT` in which I declared that a `primary key` of `TABLEA` should be `NOT IN` a subselect in which I selected the `primary key` left joined it with `TABLEB` `WHERE TABLEB.column2 = 'x'`. its not that pretty but worked!

Comment: Okay, @JeanJung if I want to join multiple `tables` with the structure of `TABLEB` im not getting all rows, because not all `tables` have the same distribution of `'x'` and `'y'` values. So I tried your approach as you suggested it, but it takes far too long to `SELECT` only two `tables`. and I have like 10 I want to join..

Comment: Ok, let me see, how many rows are you retrieving? I don't know the table structures, would be better if i could analyze all tables. The data are important too, for example, if `TABLEA` have too many child records in `TABLEB` but not in `TABLEC`, when you join the tables together the time will be better that don't join `TABLEC`. There are too many things to do with indexes and  constraints too. Tonight i will have a time, i will create some tables and see if i can help you, how many records in those tables? Can you send a summary with table - foreign keys - records number?

Comment: @JeanJung i've got a solution (see my edit), perhaps its now more insightful to you. each table have approx 40000 table rows. `unique` and `column1` are unique fields. But i dont want to bother you anylonger since im having a solution (which i dont quite understand). But if you have, perhaps, another approach for `conditional joins` Id be happy to her from you!

Comment: All those `LEFT JOINS` are really necessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82304/discussion-between-jean-jung-and-insop).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is a possible approach:

```
SELECT A.*, IF(B_X.column1 IS NOT NULL, B_X.column2, B_Y.column2), IF(B_X.column1 IS NOT NULL, B_X.column3, B_Y.column3), ...
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B B_X ON A.column1 = B_X.column1 AND B_X.column2 = 'x'
LEFT OUTER JOIN B B_Y ON A.column1 = B_Y.column1 AND B_Y.column2 = 'y'
```

You would have to list each column you want from B in an IF(), in your SELECT clause, in order to get the 'x' values before the 'y' values.